# Mailjet inline attachment using template in symfony2 with mailjet-apiv3

Tags: php, email-attachments, mailjet, inline-attachments

I am successfully able to attach inline image for my system email. I am using template which I have created in mailjet Transactional templates. Now if I use attached image in html but **I am not able to see image in my email**.

I am sending inline image like this which is working perfectly.

```
$logoFile = 'full path of image';
$inlineImg[] = [
       'Content-type' => 'image/png',
       'Filename'     => 'logo.png',
       'content'      => base64_encode(file_get_contents($logoFile))
   ];
'Inline_attachments' = $inlineImg;
```

Now, I want to see this image in my email. Using image in mailjet template like this:

```
<p>Test inline image <img src="cid:logo.png" /></p>
```

Ref: https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?php#sending-with-attached-files

Answer (score 1):

I sent them a support ticket after I ran into this problem myself. They are aware of it and working on it.

According to them, inline attached images are displayed on all major email clients except Thunderbird and GSuite (the professional version of Gmail, apparently). Their test email (the curl command in the documentation you refer to) does work with Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

In which email clients do you observe issue? There is a known issue with inline attachments not rendered properly in Thunderbird and few other minor mail clients due to the required specific "Content-type" by the mail client. Inline images should be displayed properly in all major email web services - Gmail, Yahoo etc. If one of the latter platforms are affected, please open [support ticket](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket) for additional investigation.

Comment: Thanks Zhivko for feedback, I have tested in Thunderbird, Outlook and Gmail. But not able to see inline image for img tag.